# Unwanted scrollbar in embedded jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, css, jsfiddle

Ok, so this may look like some kind of inception, because I am hosting jsfiddle inside jsfiddle, although on my personal website the effect is the same and I've already tested it in IE and Chrome, so... On the results page there is scrollbar attached and when content is long enough the second one is added as well, which looks and function really bad for me. Anyone has/seen fix for that?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/axxveyj5/)

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" src="//jsfiddle.net/0cb1hr52/1/embedded/result" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Thanks

Here is what I see:
[image]

Comment: I would suggest to use this library if you have access to both of the soruces: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer 
I'm using this a lot and it works really well makling the iframe responsive as well if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So jsfiddle renders your fiddle in a wrapper element which has it's own styles, which cause the top level iframe to scroll. See screenshot.

[image]

There is no way to change the style of that iframe because of iframe cross origin policy and because you have no control over what jsfiddle renders your code in. Perhaps we should step back and ask why you want to host a jsfiddle inside a jsfiddle in the first place. There might be a better solution to your overall goal than this question.

Comment: It's just an example, I host it on my personal website, but the behavior is the same.

Comment: right but i guess what i'm asking is there a way around it? could you maybe us a gist instead of fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to remove the middle scrollbar.

Try using [`scrolling="no"`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/axxveyj5/5/)

Comment: Thanks Zach, but I knew about that solution, though it does not work, I believe there are some nasty styles/scripts that cuts it in two.

Answer (score 0):

Okay a few things.
1) iframe is not completely supported by HTML5 so, you have very little control over the scroll bar at the moment
2) The only way to get rid of the second scroll bar is by defining the height to be bigger than the text that is being shown.
3) My suggestion for doing that is to write up some Javascript that will dynamically adjust the height of the content according to the data that is being displayed, this will get rid of the `overflow: scroll`.

**[Proof that iframe is not completely supported](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)**

[JsFiddle Demo (Displaying a single scroll bar using CSS NOT Javascript)](http://jsfiddle.net/axxveyj5/)